# have a slack api token configured,for aletmanager need to make it as secret so that it is not exposed through gitlab

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

the alertmanager configmap that contains  the alertmanager.yml is shown below.I need to mask the slack url in alertmanager.yml so that gitlab users wont be able to view the incoming webhook specified in the place of **Slackurl**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: alertmanager-config
  labels:
    name: alertmanager-config
  namespace: {{ .Values.app.namespace}}
data:
  alertmanager.yml: |-
   global:
    resolve_timeout: 5m
   route:
    group_by: ['job']
    group_wait: 5m
    group_interval: 5m
    repeat_interval: 5m
    receiver: 'slack_general'
   receivers:
     - name: 'slack_general'
       slack_configs:
       - **api_url: 'Slackurl'**
         channel: '#incomingwebhooktest'
```

Comment: So if I understood the problem; you've got this code in a gitlab repository and you don't want other developers to be able to see the slackurl. Am I right? A solution could be to replace the url while deploying the service. You could add a script in the process of deploying the service which reads the configuration and replaces a pattern, in this case 'Slackurl'.

Comment: yes that is exactly am looking at .do you have a sample implementation,does it work with kubernetes secrets.